# Disable delete button if record exist in multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have here mysql records display in html table with delete button. What I need to do is disable the delete button if record is exist in both database table.

How I can disable the delete button per row if record already exist in both table? any help will appreciate.

```
$search = $mysqli1->real_escape_string($_POST['bid']);
$search = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $search);
$search = $_POST['bid'];
$res = $mysqli1->query("select * from code WHERE item LIKE '%$search%' OR item_code LIKE '%$search%' OR cat_code LIKE '%$search%' order by item_code ASC");

while($r = $res->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<tr>
<td><a href='#' id='".$r['id']."' class='del'><img src='../images/del.png'></a></td>
</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Please consider what your first three lines of code do. With this you can omit the first two, because you overwrite their result in line 3. You insert the raw input in your query. That's not what you want to do. With a little crafted input I got a delete button for every row of your code table ...

Answer (score 0):

throw in a simple if() statement
connected with the both queries
in pdo you use the ->rowCount()
not sure in mysqli

so this logic you'd need

query1 = counted rows in table1

query2 = counted rows in table2

as if you said if it exists in both tables it should hide it so you're going to work with an `if-or statement`

```
if(query1 == 0 || query2 == 0){
 //show your button
}
```

what here stands is simple:

```
if(query1 equals 0 rows OR query2 equals 0 rows){
 //show your button
}
//While you don't put up the else with something else it won't show anything
//so if there are the value of 1+ rows in both query1 and query2 this won't show anything
```

if you want me to provide a pdo example just reply

edit:

PDO Class to make it easier to connect

```
class Database extends PDO
{
    private $db;
    public function Database($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$db.";host=".$host.";",    $user, $pass);       
        } catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e) {
            die('An error has occurred! [Code: '.$e->getCode().']!  <br/>More info: ['.$e->getMessage().']!');
        }
    }
    public function runQuery($query) {
        try{
            return $this->db->query($query);
        } catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e) {
            die('An error has occurred! [Code: '.$e->getCode().']!<br/>More info: ['.$e->getMessage().']!');
        }       
    }
}
```

Now the row counting: *updated* there was a little mistake by the && and the 2x query1 check

```
 $consite = new Database('DBHost','DBUsername','DBPassword','DBName');
 $query1 = $consite->runQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE1");
 $query2 = $consite->runQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE2");
 if($query1->rowCount() == 0 || $query2->rowCount() == 0) {
  //do your while statement to loop through it
  //if you done your while statement it only shows the delete button
  //for items that are NOT in both tables
 }
```

sorry I was too lazy to add the while statement ;)
if I am correct you can check from multiple tables in a sql query so you can do it with 1 query if you make the multi check following 1 query!

edit:
Logical steps for this question:

1) `Connect` to the `database`

2) Make a `query` for `table1`

3) `Count` the `entries`(`records`) from `table1`

4) Make a `query` for `table2`

5) `Count` the `entries`(`records`) from `table2`

6) `Check` if `one` of them equals `0`

7) if `one` of them equals `0` `entries` (`records`(`rows`)) then show the button

Comment: it is my own class tho' I will update the answer with the example

Comment: so I need to use select count in my query?

Comment: can you gave me a sample of query?

Comment: I updated the thread with PDO example I use this for my stuff and I can loop fine through my email list the only thing is I used 1 table but it should work perfectly using 2

Comment: I hope my example helped you. if not please reply with what you exactly want or what goes wrong.

Comment: I tried something like this       if($res == 0 && $query2 == 0) {
echo "<td><a href='#' id='".$r['id']."' class='del'><img src='../images/del.png' height='10px' width='10px'></a></td>";
 } else {
 echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)'><img src='../images/stop.png' border='0' width='10' height='10' title='Already Add in Purchase Request' style='cursor: not-allowed;'></a></td>";
 } .. I had an error in rowCount() so I replace that. But the problem all row is disable

Comment: oki and what was your query? there is also a query that allows to count it's SELECT COUNT(`row`) AS `counter` FROM `table` then use the then fetch this `counter` data and if the fetched `counter` data equals 0 and blablabla... do the same as the e.G'ed example in my post

Comment: my query in my question is used for my search.

Comment: Did you test the query and does it work fine as you want it because you want to select something from both tables but as I can see you only have 1 table selected with your query... on this way you never can check on both tables...

Comment: I updated the answer again also show a picture how your query ends up... (in the database self)